# JQuery/Bootstrap3 plugin to display "..." dropdown for GUI lists that are too long

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of link in the bottom of my application, there are admin actions.
Sometimes, the list is longer than the width of the screen and it takes two lines to display all links.

What I want to do is: If the width taken by the list is too long then display as much links as possible and then a `...` dropdown menu that list the missing links. All links would be in one line.

I'm looking for a plugin with jQUery or/and bootstrap 3 to do this. Do you know anything that would fit my needs? I could also do it by hand but I prefer search for something existing for now.

Comment: I think this questions is more suitable for the stack-overflow site

Comment: @ArvanitisChristos I tried in the first place. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136069/plugin-list-too-long-gui-with-automatic-dropdown-jquery-bootstrap-3